# In my jekyll site, maxCDN bootstrap 4 seems to break my maxCDN font awesome

Tags: html, css, jekyll, font-awesome, bootstrap-4

> Hi Guys. Please when I add a maxcdn bootstrap 4 to my Jekyll site, it breaks my font awesome(the one inside a div in my header.html) 
>   which is delivered by my added maxcdn font awesome. Can anyone be of help? Attached is my head.html(link to the maxcdn bootstrap 4 commented out), header.html, main.css and two screenshots of the different scenarios([screenshot1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/se2e8ku0gq19xbm/2017-11-02%20%281%29.png?dl=0), [screenshot2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3b4a2i5mg0l4d2r/2017-11-02%20%287%29.png?dl=0)) I think the styling of the icons-header div(containing the icons in the header.html) is the culprit. the icons-header is mentioned around the middle of the main.css. Cheers guys

```
//head.html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>{% if page.title %}{{ page.title }}{% else %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %}</title>
  <meta name="description" content="{% if page.description %}{{ page.description | strip_html | strip_newlines | truncate: 160 }}{% else %}{{ site.description }}{% endif %}">
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/konpa/devicon/master/devicon.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.1/css/mdb.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
</head>

//header.html
<div id="particles-js">
  <div class="content">

      <h1>
        <span class="site-title">{{site.username}}</span>
        <span class="site-description">{{site.user_title}}</span>
      </h1>
      <div class="icons-header">
        <a aria-label="Send email" href="mailto:{{site.email}}"><i class="icon fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
        <a aria-label="My LinkedIn" target="_blank" href="https://linkedin.com/in/{{site.linkedin_username}}"><i class="icon fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a aria-label="My Github" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/{{site.github_username}}"><i class="icon fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
      <a class="link" href="#about" data-scroll>About Me</a>
      <a class="link" href="#projects" data-scroll>Projects</a>
  </div>
  <a class="down" href="#about" data-scroll><i class="icon fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>

//main.css. I think the culprit is the icons-header div
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
body
{font-family:'Montserrat',sans-serif}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse{0%,to{-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)";filter:alpha(opacity=40);opacity:.4;top:0}50%{-ms-filter:none;-webkit-filter:none;filter:none;opacity:1;top:-10px}}
@keyframes pulse{0%,to{-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)";filter:alpha(opacity=40);opacity:.4;top:0}50%{-ms-filter:none;-webkit-filter:none;filter:none;opacity:1;top:-10px}}
#particles-js{
    background:#1a222c;
    display:block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:100vw;
    min-height:100vh;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed
}
#particles-js .particles-js-canvas-el{
    width:100vw!important;height:100vh!important
}
.content{
    z-index:1;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}
.content .site-title{
    font-size:50px;
    display:block;
    line-height:1
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px)
{
    .content .site-title{
        margin:0;
        font-size:100px
    }
}
.content .site-description{
    font-size:20px;
    display:block;
    line-height:1;
    margin:5px 0 10px
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
    .content .site-description{
        font-size:40px
    }
}
.content .link{
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:15px;
    margin:10px
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
    .content .link{
        font-size:20px
    }
}
.icons-header{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center
}
.icons-header .icon{
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:2px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    transition:all .7s
}
.icons-header .icon:active,.icons-header .icon:hover{
    color:#1a222c;background:#fff
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
    .icons-header .icon{
        width:35px;
        height:35px;
        font-size:35px
    }
}
.down,.icons-header,.user{
    text-align:center
}
.down{
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:25px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:30px
}
.down .icon{
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    fill:#fff;
    -webkit-animation:pulse 1.3s infinite;
    animation:pulse 1.3s infinite
}
.down .icon:active,.down .icon:hover,.footer a:active,.footer a:hover{
color:#4b5664
}
.user{
    margin:20px auto;font-size:60px
}
.user p{
    font-size:16px
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
    .user{
        font-size:75px
    }
}
.user-details{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
    margin:10px auto
}
.user-projects{
    margin:40px auto
}
.user-projects img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:5px
}
.user-projects h5,body{
    margin:0
}
.user-projects li{
    color:#1a222c;
    font-size:1.1rem
}
.user-projects p{
    margin-right:5px
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
    .images,.images img{
        float:right
    }
    .contents{margin-left:0
    }
}
.project-link{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    margin:10px 0;
    padding:5px;
    color:#1a222c;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:1px solid #1a222c;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align:center;
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:color .3s ease-out,background-color .3s ease-out,border-color .3s ease-out
}
.project-link:active,.project-link:hover{
    background-color:#54516a;
    border-color:#54516a;
    color:#fff;
    transition:color .3s ease-in,background-color .3s ease-in,border-color .3s ease-in
}
.footer{
    background:#1a222c;
    padding:10px 0;
    margin-top:100px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff
}
.footer .love{
    color:red
}
.footer a{
    text-decoration:none;margin:0;color:#fff
}
```

Comment: What does your browser's console output look like, Evan? I suspect you'll find the answer there.

Comment: your code seems like you are using `skeleton` framework and `bootstrap` framework Try to use only one to fix issues like these

Comment: @CameronHurd  @ Znaneswar Thanks for trying to help. It's the skeleton and bootstrap not co-habiting, I think because am reverse engineering the project, so some of the stylings break when I add the bootstrap.